# Setting up a global variable in django

Tags: python, django

I am using elasticsearch and need to set up a persistent connection to it which I resuse anywhere in my project. However, after much digging I am still unsure how to properly create a global var which I can be sure will only be instantiated once. I have created the following file:

**es.py**

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
```

I use it in places like tasks and views as follows:

```
import es
es.es.search(***********)
```

But to me it seems this would merely call `es = Elasticsearch()` each time, resulting in the connection being recreated. Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of the choice of module and variable names (`es.es` seems awkward), what your doing seems ok.

`Elasticsearch()` will be called only once, no matter how many times you import the module in the rest of your code.

I think you would want some way of reconnecting if the connection is lost, but that is another matter.

Answer (score 2):

It should be correct as when you `import es`, `es.py` is *executed* and all the variables are initialized and added to the context. So, using `es.es.search` would *use* the already initialized variable `es`.

Answer (score 1):

Just put this code in your settings.py file. Django will run it once and your connection will be instantiated once. And then import it from settings like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.es
```